# \@startsection, hyperref and newunicodechar; protection needed?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, expansion, unicode

When working with custom defined environments using `\@startsection` I found, after switching to `newunicodechar` for defining my unicode characters, that the sectioning headings give this peculiar output:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{lemma}
\makeatletter
\def\lemmamark{\@gobble}
\newenvironment{lemma}[1]{\@startsection{lemma}{3}{-1em}{\baselineskip}{.1\baselineskip}{\bfseries}{Lemma: #1}}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\def\textomega{ω} \newunicodechar{ω}{\ifmmode \omega \else \textomega \fi}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIXGeneral}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}{Properties of ω text}
    Some Test
\end{lemma}

\section{Properties of ω}
    More Testing

\end{document}
```

The following changes do not have any influence:

- Using standard sectioning commands instead of `\@startsection` (as shown in the example output)
- Removing the `\ifmmode` conditional (I just left it here, so that you can see the reason for using `\newunicodechar` at all)
- Using `\protect` inside of `\def\textomega`
- Using `\renewcommand` or `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define `\textomega`
- Using the predefined `\textomega`

I know that I could probably use `unicode-math` here, but I'm still on `TeX Live 2011` and didn't find it usable enough in the general situation.

I'll just post a self-answer on how to circumvent this problem, but what I'm much more interested in, is: **Why does this happen?** Is this maybe a bug in `hyperref` or `newunicodechar`?

---

It gets stranger still! With other, similar characters there is no such problem. For example ψ instead of ω will work with

```
\def\textpsi{ψ} \newunicodechar{ψ}{\ifmmode \psi \else \textpsi \fi}
```

Comment: I don't see why using `\newunicodechar`. The input will work also in math without any redefinition.

Comment: @egreg: If I just use `fontspec`'s `\setmainfont` and compile with `xelatex` the `ω` will not be printed out in math mode. Tracing gives `Missing character: There is no ω in font cmmi10!`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Probably I confused some compilations with or without some of the packages. I'd suggest to load `hyperref` as late as possible. Are you sure you don't want to load `unicode-math` and XITS Math?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `hyperref` generates bookmarks and tries to catch the bookmark titles
from LaTeX's section system. The most difficult step is the conversion from
a title given as TeX string to a string suitable for PDF bookmark titles.
First many macros are redefined to get more sensible output for bookmarks.
Also `hyperref` makes use of NFSS2 and uses encodings `PD1` and `PU` for
PDFDocEncoding or Unicode (only these two encodings are allowed in PDF bookmark strings).
Then the string is expanded (`\edef`) and in the cleanup afterwards the tokens
are checked. An important step is `\HyPsd@CheckCatcodes` that controls the tokens.
For example, `$` for switching to and from math are filtered out. Unhappily
the case of active characters is forgotten that are defined using e-TeX's
`\protected`. This is the case for character `ω` because of
`\newunicodechar`. It gets expanded in the line `\ifcat#1A% letter` of `\HyPsd@CheckCatcodes`. The expansion of `ω` expands `\textomega`, that
expands in `PU` encoding to `\83\311` the octal representation for `U+03C9`.
In this case `\8` consists of two tokens both with catcode 12 (other), the `\ifcat`
succeeds and the remaining tokens leak out: `3\311` and the `A` from the intended
token comparison.

I will fix this in `hyperref` 2012/07/30 v6.82w. An extra test for
protected active characters is added and the characters replaced by characters
with catcode 12 (other) with the same character code. However the macro text
of the active character, that might print something else, must be ignored.
Macros defined using `\protected` are not expanded in `\edef`. The only way
to support such macros and characters is to add appropriate redefinitions
of these macros for `\pdfstringdef`, e.g.:

```
\newunicodechar{ω}{ohm}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def ω{ohm}%
}
```

BTW, keep in mind that `\text<charname>` macros are usually defined
using the NFSS2 system (`\DeclareTextSymbol`, `\DeclareTextCommand`, ...). These
commands define, how the macro is typeset depending on the current encoding.
They overwrite previous definitions of the macro silently.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the following changes will remove the spurious line with “3\311A”:

- Removing the `hyperref` package
- Removing the statement with `\newunicodechar{ω}`
- Putting a `\protect` in front of `\textomega` inside of `\newunicodechar{ω}`
- Using a `\protect` like this:

  ```
  \newcommand\unichar[3]{\newunicodechar{#1}{\protect{\ifmmode#2\else#3\fi}}}
  \def\textomega{ω} \unichar{ω}{\omega}{\textomega}
  ```

The last solution has the benefit of shortness when using a lot of these statements.

---

I found out some more things. The problem is, that `fontspec` is overwriting my definition of `\textomega` and so when `ω`, defined by `\newunicodechar`, gets expanded, `fontspec`s `\textomega` is used and not mine. That explains why on the other hand using different commands from `\textomega` like `\textpsi` work: as you will be told when you try to use it, `\textpsi` is not defined in the EU1 encoding.

So I could simply do my definitions after loading `fontspec`, but there is a better solution, that completely circumvents the problem:

```
\newunicodechar{ω}{\ifmmode\omega\else ω\fi}
```

As I concluded from [one of egreg's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56697/15616), it is perfectly ok to use the unicode character itself in the argument of `\newunicodechar`. So now no `\textomega` is needed anymore.

Comment: Yes: the second argument of `\newunicodechar` is gathered immediately, so any use of the characted to be activated has already been tokenized before the definition is performed. So it's perfectly safe to use the character in the second argument.