# Strange error when unicode-math and hyperref are combined in xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref, unicode-math

The following is an MWE for a problem that I'm facing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
\section{$2\times 2$}
$2 \times 2$
\end{document}
```

When compiling this with xelatex, I get the following error:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \times 
l.7 \section{$2\times 2$}
```

But the error goes away if I remove the inclusion of the hyperref package.

Now obviously I'd like to be able to use math in a section header, and with pdflatex the compilation is fine (except for hyperref grumbling about math in bookmarks, which can be fixed by other means).

So is there something I'm doing wrong with xelatex ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a different font encoding? This looks a lot like a [problem I once had](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64986/startsection-hyperref-and-newunicodechar-protection-needed).

Comment: I haven't, but then I don't know too much about font encodings in general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An update to Ulrike's answer.

With hyperref 2012/08/13 v6.83a you can use option `unicode` (or `pdfencoding=auto`) together with option `psdextra`:

```
\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]
```

Then lots of mathematical symbols including `\times` are recognized.

Comment: Hmm. my texlive installation is 2011 and I can't merely install the 2012 version of hyperref using tlmgr.

Comment: I can't find this feature in the documentation of `hyperref` with TeXlive 2016. Is it out of sync?

Comment: @cjorssen Option `psdextra` is documented in the [`README`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\texorpdfstring` to tell hyperref to use another text for the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{$2\times 2$}{2\texttimes2}}
$2 \times 2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure. and that's what I was referring to when I said there are "other ways" of dealing with this in pdflatex. But I guess I was puzzled as to why this was happening.