# Conflict between xeCJK and hyperref in TeXLive 2012

Tags: hyperref, errors, xecjk

I find that in  the presence together of packages `hyperref` and `xeCJK`, in either order, raises an `Improper alphabetic constant` error with an em-dash in commands `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. This happens with TeXLive 2012 but not 2011. Here is an MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{hyperref}            % adds clickable links to TOC

\begin{document}
\section{O my swineherd!}
\subsection{Em-dash --- in subsection}
\end{document}
```

An en-dash does not cause the same problem.

The temporary expedient of

```
\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}
```

offered at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69354/3935 does not work here; the temporary expedient of

```
\subsection{Em-dash \texorpdfstring{---}{} in subsection}
```

following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69338/3935 does work, but I'd rather clear up the underlying problem. Any thoughts?

For now, I've reverted to TeXLive 2011.

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: @egreg: well, I've tried reinstalling TeXLive 2012 several times from different sources. What could be the problem, if it's not reproducible on your installation? I'm on Mac OS 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no error.

Update your TeX Live 2012 *online* (using `tlmgr`) instead of reinstall it (older version) time and time again.

Use `\listfiles` in the preamble to show the versions of your packages in the log. Here is mine:

> ```
> xeCJK.sty    2012/10/27 v3.0.10
> expl3.sty    2012/09/29 v4249
> fontspec.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b
> hyperref.sty    2012/10/31 v6.83l
> ```

Comment: Right you are — updating from the command line fixed it.