# Suddenly, a problem with boldface Greek symbols; bm package doesn't work

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, symbols, bold

I've added the following packages:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}
```

In addition, I started compiling(?) in XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.

As a consequence, in the math environment, the boldface (i.e. `\mathbf`) in combination with Greek letters does not work (whereas the latin letter do work). Just to clarify: I can still compile my code, but the Greek letter have become invisible in the output.

I've tried to use the `\bm` package to attempt to circumvent this problem, but it spits out the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Call@AtVeryEndDocument ...cumentHook \@undefined 
                                              \global \let \Call@AtVeryE...
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: my packages always work:-)  That error is not generated by `bm` please (always) produce a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Oh I should say `bm` doesn't really work with unicode-math, it is designed for classic 8bit math font setups.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hehe, sorry, not trying to step on anybody toes; I'm sure it is my incompetency with LaTeX. It is difficult to reproduce a small document, because I'm using man different files and let it compile by 1 main file (difficult to explain for me because I don't speak the LaTeX lingo and English is not my first language, but I hope you know what I mean). But it is exactly, how I described in my original post. The problem arrived when I added those packages. Before that everything was working fine.

Comment: `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` should do. Don't load `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. Some outdated guides tell to, but they're wrong. You should be aware of the fact that `\mathbf` only works with uppercase Greek letters (but this has always been so).

Comment: Ah great. It work exactly like berfore with `mathbf`, so I don't need to manually change everything to `bm`. Thank you @egreg!!

Comment: @Hunter You can even do better. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you load `fontspec` also the font for math upright letters is changed to use the default text font. The Greek letters in this font are not where LaTeX expects them to be: with the standard definition, `\Phi` points to slot `0x08`, while the uppercase Phi in Unicode is at `U+03A6`.

The command `\mathbf`, in standard LaTeX, only works with Latin letters and uppercase Greek. You can revert to the standard behavior by loading

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

that will use the standard Computer Modern font for upright math characters. But there's no point in not doing the big step and load

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

*but* you need `\symbf` rather than `\mathbf` (also for Latin letters).

See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$\symbf{\Phi}+\symbf{\alpha}$

$\Phi+\alpha$
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

If you don't want to do the big step, you still can get `\mathbf` to work with uppercase Greek; just teach XeLaTeX where to go and find the uppercase Greek letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \Umathchardef\Gamma   = 7 0 "0393
  \Umathchardef\Delta   = 7 0 "0394
  \Umathchardef\Theta   = 7 0 "0398
  \Umathchardef\Lambda  = 7 0 "039B
  \Umathchardef\Xi      = 7 0 "039E
  \Umathchardef\Pi      = 7 0 "03A0
  \Umathchardef\Sigma   = 7 0 "03A3
  \Umathchardef\Upsilon = 7 0 "03A5
  \Umathchardef\Phi     = 7 0 "03A6
  \Umathchardef\Psi     = 7 0 "03A8
  \Umathchardef\Omega   = 7 0 "03A9
}

\begin{document}
$\Gamma+\Delta+\Theta+\Lambda+\Xi+\Pi+\Sigma+
 \Upsilon+\Phi+\Psi+\Omega$

$\mathbf{\Gamma}+\mathbf{\Delta}+\mathbf{\Theta}+\mathbf{\Lambda}+
 \mathbf{\Xi}+\mathbf{\Pi}+\mathbf{\Sigma}+\mathbf{\Upsilon}+
 \mathbf{\Phi}+\mathbf{\Psi}+\mathbf{\Omega}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Although you can find somewhere that `xunicode` and `xltxtra` are recommended with XeLaTeX, the information is outdated and they should *not* be loaded. Only `xltxtra` can, in the unusual situation that you really need the features it provides.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Unfortunately, the `unicode-math` gives me the error: “improper alphabetic constant”. This is very similar to the problem described here:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69331/strange-error-when-unicode-math-and-hyperref-are-combined-in-xelatex, however their solution does not work for me. Nevertheless, your second suggestion works perfect for me. Thank you!

Comment: dear @egreg, now the example you provided do not produce any bold greek letter (I tried with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX). Could you update your answer?

Comment: @oibaFox I guess you meant the first document example; six years ago `\mathbf` was correct, now `\symbf` should be used.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know. In fact, using `\symbf` it works. Thank you very much.