# Is this a good way to change \section in document using luacode? Or could this be done using plain Latex macro?

Tags: sectioning, luatex, luacode, code-review

I wanted to do simple thing. Change each `\section` to `\cprotect\section` in the whole document.

I could not figure out how to do it using latex macro. So I used `lua`

I'd like to ask if you think this is an OK method or if there is a better way to do it using pure latex macro, which might be more efficient.

First will show MWE showing why I needed to do this.

If you are wondering why not use an editor and do this? It is because I can't edit the latex code itself after `\begin{document}`  because I use an Latex editor (Scientific word) which does not understand the command `\protect`. So if I modify it using a text editor outside of SW, then SW will not be able to read/understand the document any more.

But I could only do this in preamble, since I can hide preamble from SW easily.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\cos\left(  A+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}%
    this is my section
\end{document}
```

---

The above gives an error when compiling using lualatex

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 13.

! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
\math@bgroup
l.13 ...+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}
                                                  %
?
```

This version below uses lua to modify each `\section` to `\cprotect\section` on the fly, by adding code to the preamble only without modify the body of the document, which is what I wanted

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase} 

\AtBeginDocument{%
\luaexec{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer", changeSection, "changeSection" )}%
}

\begin{luacode}
function changeSection(s)  
      --texio.write_nl("Enter with s="..s)
      s = string.gsub(s,"\\section" , "\\cprotect\\section")
   return (s)
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\cos\left(  A+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}%
    this is my section
\end{document}
```

---

And now lualatex compiles it OK and output PDF is correct.

Question is: Could the above be done using direct Latex macro? I tried `renewcommand` and that does not work.

I am not unhappy with the above, but worry it might be inefficient since it has to do lots of string  searches each time on whole document. I plan to do the same for `subsection` and `subsubsection`.

Please note that I only use lualatex.

TL 2020

**Update**

For the error above, I tried the "fix" in the suggested link, it still gives the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\cos\left(  A+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}%
    this is my section
\end{document}
```

Compile using `lualatex`

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
\math@bgroup
l.13 ...+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}
                                                  %
?
```

My question here is not on the error above per say, but if there is a better way to change `\section` to `\cprotect\section` I only used this example which generates an error to try to justify why I wanted to do this in first place.

Comment: Looks more like a bug in `hyperref`.  Here is a *true* MWE: http://dpaste.com/1YXE6G2 (expires in 7 days).

Comment: Seems to be this one https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/63 and this one https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/532

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange error when unicode-math and hyperref are combined in xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69331/strange-error-when-unicode-math-and-hyperref-are-combined-in-xelatex)

Comment: @HenriMenke I am afraid it does not answer my question. 2 things. My question here is not on the error itself I get before changing section, but on if the method I used to workaround it is OK. Second, I tried the "fix" in the link you show, and I still get the error. I changed `\usepackage{hyperref}` to `\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]` and still get same error when compiling. You are feel to try it yourself as well and see. And I can't use the second "fix" there as well. So only "fix" I know, is to use `\cprotect`

Comment: @HenriMenke the true MWE is not really what I have. This problem shows up with I use `\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}` And I do not want to change this as I like this font. But again, my question here is not on the error itself, but asking if this method is OK I used and if there is a macro in Latex to do this change instead. That is all.

Comment: If you are sure that you will never use the optional argument of `\section`, then you can just write `\cMakeRobust\section` in the preamble.

Comment: The docu of cprotect describes how to add it permanently to a command, but I can't test  now

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure I understand what you mean by "optional argument of section". I only used `\section{.... name ...}`. But I tried what you suggested and it did not work. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\cMakeRobust\section

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\cos\left(  A+B\right)  $ and $\sin\left(  A+B\right)  $}%
    this is my section
\end{document}`

Comment: ... and when I compiled the above using lualatex, it gives error `(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty)) (./foo2.out) (./foo2.out)
! Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> \CPT@next

l.14 \tableofcontents

?` using TL 2020. Otherwise this would have been a very good alternative to using luacode to do this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. I will look into this and see if I can find how to do it.

Comment: @Nasser That is because `\tableofcontents` calls `\section*` and as I said you can't use optional arguments after applying `\cMakeRobust`.  You could put `\cMakeRobust\section` after `\tableofcontents` though.

Comment: while cprotect works, it also destroys the content of the bookmarks. So a easier fix is too use `\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}`, as they are useless now anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I did not know about `\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}`. It seems to do what I want and so I do not have to do `\cprotect` to add math in the section title. I tested it and it works. I do not understand what you mean by `it also destroys the content of the bookmarks`? What is bookmarks here? pdf looks fine. I click on entry in TOC and it send me to that section. (using Adobe pdf reader). What is it that gets destroyed in this process? Thanks for this. Feel free to make it answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cprotect` works as it hides the argument (it writes it to a file) and hyperref no longer can process it. But this also means that it no longer can appear in the outlines/bookmarks. Instead you only see a file name there:

[image]

So a better solution -- until a way is found to avoid that hyperref errors with such math -- is not to use bookmarks at all with

```
 \usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```