# Command \m unavailable in encoding TU

Tags: xetex, fontspec, font-encodings

I use XeLaTeX and normally do not use the `fontenc` package.  But now I want to use a specific symbol which according to the [`symbols-a4.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) needs `T4` encoding which is provided by the `fc` package.

Compiling the code below ended in

```
    ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \m unavailable in encoding TU.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 Given a data matrix $D$ (database $\m
                                          {D}$)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fclfont}
\usepackage{t4phonet}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Gebruik met xelatex
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}             % End of preamble and beginning of text.

Given a data matrix $D$ (database $\m{D}$)


\end{document}
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Linux Libertine has the `Ɗ` character available, so you can typeset it directly. But if you want the character to play nicely with `$D$` it might be easier to add the hook manually.

Comment: Do have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56692/35864, it has a LaTeX and a XeLaTeX solution.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I mark your answer as a solution?  I am not an experienced StackExchange user.

Comment: If the linked answer solved your question, we can just close your question as a duplicate.