# Write Cyrillic in equations just like Greek letters?

Tags: equations, cyrillic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What packages will let me use Cyrillic characters in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-packages-will-let-me-use-cyrillic-characters-in-math-mode)

Is there any way to get these letters in the same way as the Greek ones? So with `\theta`, etc?
I have looked around and all I found was compatibility with Russian keyboards, but I don't have one of those.

Edit:

Solved it!, any char can be represented by this code. It works in both text and equations.

```
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\textcyr[1]{{\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand\Zhe{ \text{\textcyr{Zh}}}
\newcommand\zhe{ \text{\textcyr{zh}}}
```

Leaving this here for future generations.

I'll self answer as soon as I can (not enough rep to do it now, if someone could help, I will vote you up :p)

Comment: another method for using just single cyrillic letters in math can be found in an answer in the [ams author faq](http://www.ams.org/author-faq/).  search for "cyrillic"; only one answer will appear.  this uses the wncy fonts that are compatible with computer modern.  i don't have time now to repeat the details here, but if this is useful, i will make an effort to turn it into a more complete answer.