# Is there a \text... command for Cyrillic characters?

Tags: macros, characters, cyrillic, alphabet

I am trying to get the Cyrillic variant of the Serbian alphabet and was wondering if there was an easy `\text` command for Cyrillic characters?

For example, I can easily get the letter З by typing `\textrevepsilon`, but is there a similar operation for the letters Б б, Г г, Д д, Ђ ђ, Ж ж, Л л, Љ љ, Њ њ, П п, Ћ ћ, Ф ф, Ц ц, Ч ч, Џ џ, Ш ш?

I realise this is *most* of the alphabet, but some of the symbols may be used in, e.g., maths, and someone may have a simple command for that symbol.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-packages-will-let-me-use-cyrillic-characters-in-math-mode