# I just want to write \Sha without ruining everything

Tags: fonts, math-mode, cyrillic

I realize similar questions have been asked before but I am not satisfied with any of the answers I've seen. I would like to use the Cyrillic letter `Ш` to denote a particular group in mathematics. Most solutions involve using `OT2` or `T2A` encoding; for example, at http://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/tex/samp-l/sha.html. However, this makes the other text in the document look bad.

For example, using the solution above, I get

[image]

while I would like to have

[image]

The first seems to be shaded strangely and the characters don't seem to align right.

Does anyone know how I can write the character `Ш` (in math mode) without changing the default font for the rest of the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-packages-will-let-me-use-cyrillic-characters-in-math-mode? The "shading" is probably due to the fact that you don't have the Type1 Cyrillic font. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg Hi egreg, I did see that but I'm not completely satisfied. I would really like to use the default text, and the code there changes it to something quite like the first image. I am using MikTeX 2.9. Thank you!

Comment: The quality of the image is not really good. Can you add a minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg I am using the code from http://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/tex/samp-l/sha.html

Comment: I don't see any blurring or "shading", both with Vojta's code and mine. Did you install the CM-Super package (for the T2A solution)? I really don't know what MiKTeX package provides the Type1 fonts for OT2.

Comment: @egreg As far as I know, I don't have the CM-Super package. Maybe this is the problem? Adding the command "\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}" alone is enough to make my document look like http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/LST/lst.pdf in terms of characters not being aligned. To me the shading seems strange as well although maybe this is not the right word. If it is just a Miktex problem then I won't worry about it, this is not very important in my document and I can use "TS" instead

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the problem. For Vojta's solution you should have the `amsfonts` package.

Comment: if you don't mind using the old `wncy` fonts, there is a "recipe" for exactly this in [the ams author faq](http://www.ams.org//faq?faq_id=164).  no extra packages needed.  if you are happy with this suggestion, i will post the actual code as an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not familiar with wncy fonts, but I would be interested to see your suggestion

Comment: One can also use `\DeclareFontEncoding{OT2}{}{} % to enable usage of cyrillic fonts
  \newcommand{\textcyr}[1]{%
    {\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}%
     \selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\Sha}{{\mbox{\textcyr{Sh}}}}` (works both in text and math modes).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

for someone who wants to use just one or two cyrillic letters in math, in a computer modern setting, the old `wncy` fonts are still distributed in tex live as part of the `amsfonts` collection, in type 1 format.  (but they don't require use of the `amsfonts` package.)

this is the recommendation in the ams author faq.

> I want to use some cyrillic letters for math variables, but there isn't any LaTeX support for cyrillic in the AMSfonts packages. How do I do it?
>
> The following four lines will load the upright cyrillic font and define `\Sh` to access the letter "Sha".
>
> ```
>     \DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
>     \DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
>     \DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}
>     \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sh}{\mathord}{mcy}{"58}
> ```
>
> The location of a cyrillic letter in the `wncyr` font can be found by looking at the chart in the AMSFonts User's Guide or at a font chart created by TeXing the file `testfont.tex` (included in every TeX system).

the user's guide can be accessed with `texdoc amsfonts` or `texdoc amsfndoc`.

Comment: This is exactly what's done in http://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/tex/samp-l/sha.html that the OP linked, with the only difference that the U encoding is used instead of OT2.

Comment: @egreg -- true, but this doesn't require `fontenc`.  (some of us still live and work in the "dark ages".)

Answer (score 2):

In a modern TeX installation, and if you want to use any other font, you either want to declare your symbol font in TU/Unicode (where it is in the slot `"0448`) or, if you are using 8-bit legacy fonts, in the T2A encoding (where it is in slot `"F8`).  This should have character class mathalpha if it should be a letter, or `mathop` if it is supposed to be typeset like ln *x*.

Another approach that works regardless of what encoding you use is to wrap an arbitrary text command inside `\text` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Scale = 1.0]

\newcommand\sh[1]{\ensuremath{\mathop{\text{\normalfont ш}}#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ \sh(x), \sh y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

This is a little more complicated in PDFTeX, but still works transparently with any font.  For example, `\usepackage{type1ec}` to use CM-Super, or `\usepackage{cmlgc}` to use CM extended, or the font of your choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\sh[1]{\ensuremath{\mathop{\text{\normalfont\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ш}}#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ \sh(x), \sh y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: PDFTeX font sample]

Comment: Why does `\sh` take an argument?  That doesn't seem to be necessary at all.

Comment: @HenriMenke You’re right, you could eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

This works!

```
%Sha:
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
%end of Sha
```

Answer (score 0):

One hack could be to use:

```
\newcommand{\Sha}{\textls[0]{III}}
```

Which reduces the width between "I" characters and looks close enough. Just putting it out there.