# How type 'E' rotated counterclockwisely by 90 degree?

Tags: letters

I guess it is a greek letter but couldn't find out how to use latex to type it out.[image]

Comment: It's not Greek it's Cyrillic, it's the Russian 'sh' (actually pronounced /ʂ/ in Russian) and will have similar or identical pronunciations in other languages that use the Cyrillic script: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha_(Cyrillic)

Comment: Possibly of some use? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/i-just-want-to-write-sha-without-ruining-everything

Comment: @Au101 thank you. that also helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find the symbol in http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. You might find it in http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive. See also [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character).

Until someone posts a better solution, you might want to go with this.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\Varpi}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Pi\kern-0.361em\Pi$}}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

This \Varpi{} works.

This A $\Varpi$ B and $A \Varpi B$, too.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, the symbol requested really is a cyrillic Sha, and the question is a duplicate of the question linked in a comment.  that's not the *only* way to get this symbol though.  depending on what font is used, with `utf8` input there are other methods; see [What packages will let me use Cyrillic characters in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14633/579) for possibilities.

Comment: Indeed. I was not aware of Ш and was pretty sure that there is a better solution: "Until someone posts a better solution...". I hope that mixing different fonts works well in this case.