# Symbol for the Lobachevsky function in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

The Lobachevsky function is an commonly used special function defined by an integral formula. In Milnors chapter from Thurston's notes, which have been typeset into latex and are available here: http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/7.pdf (the definition of the function is on the first page), he uses a Cyrillic character to denote it (the first letter of Lobacheski's name, a Cyrillic El). I would like to know how this symbol was rendered, or a way to get a similar result by a simple command in math mode.

Comment: With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and may be loading `babel` with the `russian` language, you might be able to use `\newcommand*\loba{\textnormal{л}}`. I have not tried since I can't compile right now.

Comment: You could also look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124746/2417). I think you would just need to change `58` to `6C`.

Comment: My 5 cents: This notation isn't well-thought, the small cyrillic l is visually to close to a small greek letter pi.

Comment: The recipe given in Ian Thompson's comment works fine. I also agree with jknappen's remark. To get a capital L in cyrillic one can use 4C instead of 6C (the full font chart is on p. 33 of the documentation for amsfonts: ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf)

Comment: @JeanRaimbault -- since some browsers have problems reaching the ams ftp server, an alternate option is http://mirrors.ctan.org//fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf or simply `texdoc amsfndoc` on a tex live system.