# Russian symbols in equations

Tags: math-mode, symbols, russian

It is some time since I used Latex, but am now up-and-
running again and using pdflatex.
I want to insert a Russian symbol (in particular the symbol sh, as in sh(x), to indicate a row of delta functions) into an equation that is contained in an eqnarray and I don't want to be forced to have a space on either side of the symbol. I can manage to type Russian symbols in straight-forward text, but so far not in an array. Can anyone help?

Answers:

Just found some excellent answers to my question. These were posted some years ago, they seemed to pop-up when I browsed around my question. Not exactly sure how I found them, but one was submitted by a lady name of Barbara. It involves the fuction \Sha.

Many thanks

Comment: (1) [AVOID `eqnarray`! AVOID `eqnarray`!](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) (2) Please add a minimal example code (and that symbol itself) so that we can test.

Comment: If you are using `pdftex` you might find this useful: [I just want to write \Sha without ruining everything](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124746/82917). If you are using different engines then you should post some minimal code.