# Notation of Cyrillic symbol in Math Reviews of AMS-Latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cyrillic

When I was writing Math Reviews of AMS, no `\usepackage`, `\newcommand`, etc could be allowed. 
How could I input the notation of Tate--Shafarevich group `\Sha`, which is a Cyrillic symbol?

I've tried

```
${\mbox{\usefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}\CYRSH}}$
```

and other possibilities, but this does need the package `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is and what is not allowed, maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124746/ would work? That doesn't use any packages.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, but \Declare... does not allowed either.

Comment: Does inserting the Unicode character in your UTF-8 source work?

Comment: The answer linked by @Marijn should have the information you need, although it's indirect.  Check the AMS fonts documentation; unless memory fails, it contains instructions for accessing the cyrillic font, specifically using `\Sha` as an example.  (`texdoc amsfndoc`)  (But if this fails, send a message to MR asking for instructions. They surely use this notation.)

Comment: @Davislor -- As of last summer, Math Reviews was nowhere near being able to use Unicode notation.  If it appears in something sent to them, they'll have to translate it to whatever they can use.

Comment: @Shawn -- If you have access to MathSciNet, and know of a review that includes `\Sha`, you can access that review and I believe look at how it's coded.  I no longer have access, so am unable to check.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've looked up the `amsfndoc`, just input 

`\newfam\cyrfam
\font\tencyr=wncyr10
\font\sevencyr=wncyr7
\font\fivecyr=wncyr5
\def\cyr{\fam\cyrfam\tencyr\cyracc}
\textfont\cyrfam=\tencyr \scriptfont\cyrfam=\sevencyr
\scriptscriptfont\cyrfam=\fivecyr`.

Then `{\cyr Sh}` works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of summer 2019, Math Reviews was still based on a plain TeX production stream, so any purely LaTeX methods aren't going to work.

The `amsfonts` documentation (`texdoc amsfndoc`) contains instructions for accessing the cyrillic font.
Here are the details for loading the font:

```
\newfam\cyrfam
\font\tencyr=wncyr10 \font\sevencyr=wncyr7 \font\fivecyr=wncyr5
\def\cyr{\fam\cyrfam\tencyr\cyracc}
\textfont\cyrfam=\tencyr \scriptfont\cyrfam=\sevencyr \scriptscriptfont\cyrfam=\fivecyr
```

Then `{\cyr Sh}` works, or this definition provides `\Sha`:

```
\def\Sha{{\cyr Sh}}
```

It's not mode-specific, and can be used in either math or text, but for the sake of clarity in the source, it's best to specify math mode if it represents a math object.