# How to use Cyrillic letter as a mathematical symbol?

Tags: symbols, cyrillic

I want to use `\cyrgup` in my document for some derivations. Is there any package that needs to be installed?

Comment: What should this symbol look like? Please post an image and take a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14 first. How did you come up with this command? Never heard of it but I suppose you read it somewhere.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-packages-will-let-me-use-cyrillic-characters-in-math-mode for how to use the letter in math mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other fonts. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/LaTeX-Package-Repositories/ucs/blob/main/config/cyrillic.ucf), the command `\cyrgup` is a mapping to the unicode [U+0491](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0491/index.htm) *CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER GHE WITH UPTURN*. Here are the [available fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0491/fontsupport.htm) and you may fonts installed on your machine to see the possible symbols.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gentium}

\begin{document}
\cyrgup
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\cyrgup}{\symbol{"0491}}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{code2000.ttf}
    \cyrgup
    \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
    \cyrgup
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}
    \cyrgup
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond}
    \cyrgup
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \cyrgup 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `\cyrgup` command is defined in the `T2A` font encoding (cyrillic and not greek...), so it should suffice to load the package `fontenc` with that encoding table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\cyrgup
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]