# Number codes for cyrillic letters

Tags: letters, cyrillic

The command

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
```

produces the russian letter Sha (III)

Which number do I have to replace 58 with in order to get the labial b?

Comment: See page 33 of http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf.  Do you mean `"62` or `"42`??

Comment: Do you mean б (lowercase) or Б (uppercase)? Its name is “be” and comes in alphabetical order after “a” and before “ve” (Вв); I understand a Spaniard is likely to confuse them. ;-)

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14687/4427?

Comment: Thanks. "See page 33..." is what I needed. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

With `unicode-math`, use the Unicode value (I think `"0411`) or just type in the letter.

With a legacy 8-bit font, look up the T2A encoding chart in Appendix A.1 of [The LaTeX Font Encoding Guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf).

With either of these, you could load your Cyrillic text font, then use something like `\newcommand\mathBe{\mathord{\textnormal{Б}}}`.  (You might actually prefer to inherit `\bfseries` from the surrounding text, for chapter or section headings.  If so, use `\textup` or `\textit` instead of `\textnormal`.)  You could also type in `^^^^0411`, which always means the Unicode codepoint U+0411 regardless of the current font encoding, instead of Б.  With `fontspec` or `unicode-math`, this is set up for you.  In legacy NFSS mode, you’d need to load `\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}` and load a font package that supports Cyrillic.  (UTF-8 input is now the default in LaTeX.)

With the even older AMS Cyrillic font, check out [the amsfonts documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf) (As Steven B. Segletes said in his comment.)