# Russian in mathematics document

Tags: languages

I would like to use russian letters in my mathematical documents.  How can I do so ?  Will I need to call specific commands for each letter or can I just introduce UTF8 codes in my document ?

I am using `lualatex` for generating documents.

I do not see any direct discussion on introducing  the characters as UTF8 symbols rather than using a command as is done with greek symbols.

[What packages will let me use Cyrillic characters in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/what-packages-will-let-me-use-cyrillic-characters-in-math-mode)

Latex supports standard Cyrillic font encodings (`T2A`, `T2B`, `T2C`, `X2`) and various Cyrillic input encodings, which form the `cyrillic` bundle.  I wonder what I need to specify because I see people basically setting `T2A`.

I do wonder how it ass be much better if we also just enter the `UTF8` characters directly for Greek rather than the `\alpha` way.

For instance I would want to include russian letters in math mode as we often do with greek letters.

```
$ я = \frac{1}(3) к $
```

Comment: Are you willing and able to employ either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document? Please advise.

Comment: Can you please add a couple of examples of what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

You want to set up a symbol font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[
  NFSSFamily=libs,
]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrmath}{TU}{libs}{m}{n}% or it?
\Umathcode`я = "7 \symcyrmath `я
\Umathcode`к = "7 \symcyrmath `к

\begin{document}

$ я = \frac{1}{3} к $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `unicode-math` loads `amsmath`?

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison, using `optex`you can say:

```
\fontfam[newcm]
$$ я = {1 \over 2} к $$
\bye
```

and you get:

[image]